# PDF looks different from print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

When I create a map in print composer the map looks exactly how I want it, but when I save it as a PDF some of the sympbols have changed. Note the roads are still visible in the PDF but some have changed to be a light grey, from the black that they are suppose to be? Why is it doing that and how do I fix it? If I unselect print as a raster, then the colours of the map change all together.
Map as seen in print composer.
[image]
PDF as raster.
[image]

Comment: Did you try opening the pdf with another pdf viewer? If yes, is the problem present in all programs? Because at least in Adobe Reader there are options to smooth lines/images, which can sometimes cause problems with rendering (thin) lines.

Comment: A workaround that may work for you is to generate an image from your composer (in high quality) and then create a PDF using this image. You will get the exact view you had in your composer.

Comment: I confirm that PDF are rendered differently by different programs. However, most people are sadly using Adobe's, so presumably @Val would like a solution for this one.

Comment: After you added the map to the print composer, did you change any layer styles or turn off any layers in the QGIS project? The composer map *display* isn't updated automatically when you make changes to the project, however any changes will be reflected in the output. So it's a good idea to refresh the composer display before exporting, to make sure what you see is what you export.